# What does "not biting" mean?

Tags: idioms

In a recent exchange with a highly eloquent friend (we were discussing a particularly peculiar episode he has pointed to me in a book) he replied to my comments on the episode with an idiom I've never heard before (being an ESL guy). He said literally "Not biting, eh?". What does this mean?

Comment: why didn't you ask him?

Comment: I did, he took it as me denying I was not biting, the reaction I only completely understood after I asked this question

Comment: It turns out he was just using the passage as "bait" to get you "hooked" on the book.  Much like adverstising, but in this case, actually for a good cause (being well-read is always a good cause).  And since you didn't "take the bait", you were "not biting".  In a more alarming context, someone may try to get you into an argument intentionally by "baiting" you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

"Not taking the bait", from fishing, meaning someone offered you a conversational opening (or an invitation to an argument) and you didn't follow up.

Answer (score 14):

*To bite* in this context means "to respond to a provocation or temptation". The phrase is understood to refer to a fish biting a baited hook, or possibly to Eve biting into the forbidden fruit.

So in context, something had happened that your friend expected to elicit a response from you. When you didn't respond as expected or intended, he remarked that you were "not biting".

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are great. Another way it's used is when I read a provocative article (as JSB suggests) and in response I'd say "Ok, I'll bite." I then offer my thoughts on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Interviewer: Why....it's OK to go into the movies and enjoy the violence?

Quentin Tarantino (Annoyed): Yeah...well...it is a movie. It's a fantasy, it's a fantasy, it is not real life. It's a fantasy. You go and you watch...you know...you watch...you watch a Kung-fu movie, and one guy takes on a hundred people in a restaurant. That's fun.

Interviewer: But why are you so sure there is no link between enjoying movie violence and enjoying real violence?

Quentin Tarantino (furious): I don't...I....well...I am gonna tell you why I am so sure. Don't....don't ask me questions like that. I am...**I am not biting**. I refuse your question.

Comment: This is a fascinating exchange. Where did you find it? (Also: Please note that your answer doesn't actually explain what "not biting" means; it just gives a context in which one (famous) person used the phrase.)

Comment: [Interview video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u7ER_q0B1-I)
Yes, I am aware that it doesn't answer the question directly, but giving the context can help memorize the meaning of the word more than just knowing its definition